# Does . invoke sh and source invoke bash?

Tags: bash, shell

If I do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
.  "$HOME/.foo/bar.sh"
```

will it invoke/load that `bar.sh` script with `sh`?

is it any different than:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source "$HOME/.foo/bar.sh"
```

Comment: Both load the script into the current shell, whatever that may be (wherever the syntax is valid); no other shell is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you source another script in a `bash` script, then it's `bash` that sources that other script. The two command that you list are equivalent in `bash`.

Comment: yeah still trying to figure out why sh is being run from a bash parent shell lol thanks

Comment: It is worth noting that the `source` built-in (but not `.`) is a Bash extension, possibly inspired by the command of the same name in csh.  It is not in the specifications for the POSIX shell.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I believe this is where the question actually comes from. Alexander is aware that `source` is a `bash` extension and that `.` is not, so he wonders if `.` would invoke `sh` (which it doesn't).